# Как сгруппировать элементы списка

Tags: python, массивы

Как можно из данного списка:

```
stats = [
{
   "userid": "123", 
   "nick": "user", 
   "count": 5
}, 

{
   "userid": "321", 
   "nick": "user2", 
   "count": 5
}, 

{
   "userid": "123", 
   "nick": "user", 
   "count": 5
}
]
```

Сделать такой:

```
[
{
   "userid": "123", 
   "nick": "user", 
   "count": 10
}, 

{
   "userid": "321", 
   "nick": "user2", 
   "count": 5
}
]
```

Comment: у вас всегда полные дубликаты по всем трем полям? А есои одно или два поля различаются - как должен выглядеть результат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действия:

- Объединение списка по `userid` в словарь с суммированием значения `count`
- Получение значения словаря в список

Пример:

```
user_id_by_data = dict()
for x in stats:
    user_id = x['userid']
    if user_id not in user_id_by_data:
        user_id_by_data[user_id] = x
    else:
        data = user_id_by_data[user_id]
        data['count'] += x['count']

print(list(user_id_by_data.values()))
# [{'userid': '123', 'nick': 'user', 'count': 10}, {'userid': '321', 'nick': 'user2', 'count': 5}]
```

Comment: а как мне с ``list(user_id_by_data.values()`` достать значение ключа ``userid`` ?

Comment: Работайте как с списком, у которого внутри словари: `items = list(user_id_by_data.values())` `for x in items: print(x["userid"])`

Answer (score -1):

Можно так:

```
stats = [
{
   "userid": "123", 
   "nick": "user", 
   "count": 5
}, 

{
   "userid": "321", 
   "nick": "user2", 
   "count": 5
}, 

{
   "userid": "123", 
   "nick": "user", 
   "count": 5
}
]

r = []
for stat in stats:
    if stat not in r:
        r += [stat]

print(r)
```